# Xpath: how to get the text of <a> tag inside a <p> tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have the following issue when trying to get information from some website using scrapy.

I'm trying to get all the text inside `<p>` tag, but my problem is that in some cases inside those tags there is not just text, but sometimes also an `<a>` tag, and my code stops collecting the text when it reaches that tag.

This is my Xpath expression, it's working properly when there aren't  tags contained inside:

```
description = descriptionpath.xpath("span[@itemprop='description']/p/text()").extract()
```

Comment: can you also post your original input and expected output? In general to get all child nodes recursively you simply use // so in your case `p//text()` should do the trick

Comment: As an alternative, if `span[@itemprop='description']/p` matches only 1 node, you can use the simpler `string(span[@itemprop='description']/p)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting [Pawel Miech's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276348/xpath-how-to-get-the-text-of-a-tag-inside-a-p-tag#comment35625143_23276348) as an answer as it appears his comment has helped many of us thus far and contains the right answer:

Tack `//text()` on the end of the xpath to specify that text should be recursively extracted.

So your xpath would appear like this:

```
span[@itemprop='description']/p//text()
```